# There was an error in serializing body of message

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

When I run on my PC in the VS2010 IDE or as an EXE, it works. But when I run on another box through a scheduler, I get the error:

```
There was an error in serializing body of message MyClassSoapIn: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\xvjzdxjt.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
```

Could this be a permissions issue? Its using the temp folder. Would that be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

So, you've probably got a similar problem to the one I had...

The error you see is because VS needs to write info to a temporary file location during the compilation and/or run processes, and VS doesn't have the necessary rights/permissions for the specified location.

The temp directory is specified by the TEMP (and sometime TMP) environment variables.

```
WindowsKey + Pause > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
```

Note that there are 2 categories on environment variables, User and System.

You've probably deleted the USER variables, leaving only the SYSTEM variables.

What happens is that VS looks for the env variable TEMP, can't find any value for the USER variable, and so uses the SYSTEM variable instead.  Problem is, VS doesn't have write access to the location specified by the SYSTEM TEMP var.

So, to fix, simply re-create and define the USER TEMP, TMP env vars to use the correct value of '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp', so that VS will now find and use the correct location where it has file write rights.

Alternatively, you might just want to change the location to which TEMP/TMP points to a place where you're guaranteed that rights won't be an issue for you.

Comment: A coworker of mine had this same issue and this solution worked for us. In his case his temp folder was in `C:\Windows\Temp` which very few applications would have access to. _why would you ever want your temp folder inside of your Windows folder anyway? Yuck._